# Unable to correctly return and store my mysqli result

Tags: php

I am trying to return my mysqli result and store it in a static variable so that I can pass it on to another function. As you can see below the second function needs to be able to read the result from the first one. The scope problem should have been fixed with returning and storing it then storing my function within a variable inside the second function:

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not working?  It works for things like my database connection.

---

```
    function profile_info() {
            $connection = database();
            static $result;

            $query = "SELECT id, name, first_name, last_name, birthdate, occupation, status
                      FROM users";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            return $result;
    }
```

I then store the returned result within my function below `$result = profile_info():

```
function users_overview () {
    $connection = database();

    $result = profile_info();

    echo "<div id='users_overview'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        if (!empty($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 'Online') {
            $status = "<div class='online'></div>"; 
        }
        else {
            $status = "<div class='offline'></div>";
        }

    include 'php/core/age_converter.php';

    include 'php/includes/profile_information.php';

    }
    echo "</div>";
}
users_overview();
```

Comment: define `static $result;` outside function

Comment: @SatenderK is there a different way? I would like to keep it inside if possible

Comment: @SatenderK outside wont do the job by the way. It has to be inside of my function

Comment: make global inside `users_overview()`

Comment: @SatenderK I prefer not using globals

Comment: seems two time  "$connection = database();" is being called when you include the call to "profile_info();" in users_overview ()

Comment: @n01ze same issue mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: If the connection was twice then it would send me an error stating such

Comment: @Asperger yep that right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems two time `$connection = database();` is being called when you include the call to `profile_info();` from `users_overview ()`

Check now if it works now,

```
function profile_info() {
                $connection = database();
                static $result;

                $query = "SELECT id, name, first_name, last_name, birthdate, occupation, status
                          FROM users";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                return $result;
        }



    function users_overview () {

        $result = profile_info();

        echo "<div id='users_overview'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            if (!empty($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 'Online') {
                $status = "<div class='online'></div>"; 
            }
            else {
                $status = "<div class='offline'></div>";
            }

        include 'php/core/age_converter.php';

        include 'php/includes/profile_information.php';

        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    users_overview();
```

Comment: What do you say about that method or is my way ok for procedural work?

Comment: That would be good choice ! But I see no use of using anonymous function here @Asperger

Comment: Problem not solved. It seems the connection is not the issue

Comment: ok try putting all your profile_info() code inside users_overview just for debugging , and see if it works

Answer (score -1):

As you don't want to globally define the variable and you can use the OOPs Concept. Data will be wrap in object. I wrote a code for you.

class user{

```
private $conn;
private $result;
function __construct(){
    $conn1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "siteData");
    $this->setConn($conn1);
}

public function profile_info(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $num = $this->getConn();
    $result = $num->query($query);
    return $result;
}

 function users_overview () {
    $result = $this->profile_info();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //get your result
    }
}
 function setConn($conn1){
    $this->conn = $conn1;
    return $this->conn;
 }

 function getConn(){
    return $this->conn;
 }
```

}

```
$temp = new user();
```

$temp->users_overview();